# How to prove that $\det(Z_{n}) = \det(Z_{n-1}) - \det(Z_{n-2})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, recurrence-relations, determinant

I'm given an $n \times n$ matrix $Z_{n}$ over $\mathbb{N}$ of which the entry in the $x$-th row and the $y$-th column equals 1 if $|x-y| < 1 $ or $ |x-y| = 1$ and zero otherwise. I'm trying to prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $n > 1$, the following statement holds.

$\det(Z_{n}) = \det(Z_{n-1}) - \det(Z_{n-2})$.

I tried proving this by induction but I'm not really sure how to use induction on recurrence relations, I only got that for $n = 2$ this must be right considering $\det(Z_{1}) =\det(Z_{0}) = 1$  and $\det(Z_{2}) = 0$ considering $Z_{2} =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$.

Comment: $|x-y|\leq1$ would be slightly shorter. Since it relies on the determinant of smaller matrices, cofactor expansion would probably help.

Comment: P.s. it's not so clear that $\det Z_0$ is well-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use cofactor expansion on the first row of $Z_n$ to find the determinant.

$\det(Z_n)=\underbrace{\left|\begin{matrix}
1&1&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&\ddots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\ddots&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&1&1
\end{matrix}\right|}_{n}\\=
1\times\underbrace{\left|\begin{matrix}
1&1&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&\ddots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\ddots&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&1&1
\end{matrix}\right|}_{n-1}+
(-1)\times\underbrace{\left|\begin{matrix}
\not1&\not1&\not0&\not\cdots&\not0&\not0&\not0\\
1&\not1&1&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&\not1&1&\ddots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\not\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&\not0&0&\ddots&1&1&0\\
0&\not0&0&\cdots&1&1&1\\
0&\not0&0&\cdots&0&1&1
\end{matrix}\right|}_{n}\\=
\det(Z_{n-1})+
(-1)\times\underbrace{\left|\begin{matrix}
1&1&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&1&\ddots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&\ddots&1&1&0\\
0&0&\cdots&1&1&1\\
0&0&\cdots&0&1&1
\end{matrix}\right|}_{n-1 \text{ (expand on first column)}}\\=
\det(Z_{n-1})+
(-1)\times\underbrace{\left|\begin{matrix}
1&\ddots&0&0&0\\
\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&\ddots&1&1&0\\
0&\cdots&1&1&1\\
0&\cdots&0&1&1
\end{matrix}\right|}_{n-2}=\det(Z_{n-1})-\det(Z_{n-2})$

Comment: I'm not really sure as to why you can conclude that the second-last step gives us $ \det(Z_{n-2})$,  is it because the column expansions leave the $Z_{n-2}$ matrix intact?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this hint will help :)

[image: Matrix induction hint]

As @Element118 says, think about the co-factor expansion (this is the usual way you compute the determinant when you first learn about it in linear algebra).

Answer (score 0):

Considering $\mathrm{det}(Z_1) =\mathrm{det}(Z_0) = 1.$

For, $n = 2$, 
$$Z_2 =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\mathrm{det}(Z_2) =\mathrm{det}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
= 1\cdot \mathrm{det}(Z_1) - 1\cdot 1\cdot \mathrm{det}(Z_0)=\mathrm{det}(Z_1) - \mathrm{det}(Z_0)(=0).$$

For, $n = k$, 
$$Z_k =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 0\\
        \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &  &\vdots \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1   \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\mathrm{det}(Z_k) = \mathrm{det}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 0\\
        \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &  &\vdots \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1   \end{pmatrix}_{k\times k}$$
$$= 1\cdot \mathrm{det}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 0\\
       \vdots &\vdots & \vdots &  &\vdots \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{pmatrix}_{(k-1)\times (k-1)}
 - 1\cdot \mathrm{det}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & \dots & 0\\
        0 & 1 & \dots & 0\\
       \vdots &\vdots &  &\vdots \\
        0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{pmatrix}_{(k-1)\times (k-1)}$$

[Expanded based on the $R_1$.]

$$
= 1\cdot \mathrm{det}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 0\\
       \vdots &\vdots & \vdots &  &\vdots \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{pmatrix}_{(k-1)\times (k-1)}
-1\cdot 1 \cdot \mathrm{det}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 0\\
       \vdots &\vdots & \vdots &  &\vdots \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{pmatrix}_{(k-2)\times (k-2)}$$
[The second part is expanded based on the $C_1$.]
$$
=\mathrm{det}(Z_{(k-1)})-\mathrm{det}(Z_{(k-2)}).$$